# NFL Jersey Collection

Tags: combinatorics

Tammy and Tommy both collect Detroit Lions jerseys. They each have a complete collection of all $n$ possible jerseys, with no jersey number repeating. They each decide to wear some of the jerseys out of their collection (possibly different numbers of jerseys). Tommy decides he wants to be wearing at least every single jersey that Tammy is wearing. 

a.) How many ways are there for Tammy and Tommy to pick jerseys such that Tommy is wearing all of the jerseys that Tammy is? 

b.) How many ways are there for Tommy and Tammy to pick jerseys such that Tommy is wearing all the jerseys that Tammy is, and at least one more jersey? 

Assume that the jerseys can be worn in any order, the collection is unordered, and that not wearing a jersey is not allowed. 

**For part a, I want to say the answer is just n ways because the question says that Tommy is wearing at least the same jerseys that Tammy is, but I feel like this makes the answer to simple and then I do not know how else to view the problem.**

Comment: You deleted your previous question. I'd like it if you undeleted it and then accepted my answer over there. Keep the questions on this site!

Answer (score 1):

In (a), there are three possible conditions for each jersey:

- it is not worn by either
- it is worn by Tommy but not by Tammy
- it is worn by both

These conditions are independent of each other, so the number of ways is $3^n$.

For (b) we need to subtract from (a)'s answer the number of ways Tommy and Tammy can wear exactly the same jerseys. This second number is computed the same way as in (a) except that the "worn by Tommy only" condition is omitted, and works out to $2^n$. The final answer is $3^n-2^n$.